# Proof by minimal counter example

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, examples-counterexamples, solution-verification

So I'm trying to solve the following question:
Prove by the smallest (minimal) counter example that for every nonnegative $n,3\mid (2^{2n}-1)$

I know the first step is to plug $0$ in for n:
$2^{2(0)}-1 = 0$
and 0 is divisible by 3 because $0$ is divisible by everything

Then you assume $3\mid (2^{2n}-1)$ is false
But this is the part where I can't figure out how to solve it, what I've done so far is:

So you take n-1 and plug that in instead of n, because if the statement $3\mid (2^{2n}-1)$
 is the smallest possible counterexample then using n-1 the statement should be true.
$2^{2(n-1)} -1 = 3k$ (k is some integer) 
$4^{n-1} = 3k + 1 $

Then I think you're supposed to multiply both sides by 4 because that would make $4^{n-1}$ just $4^{n}$ which we assume to not be divisible by 3
$4(4^{n-1} = 3k + 1) $

The problem is if you simplify it the left side "match up" to the original equation
$4^{n}-4=12k $ While the right side IS a multiple of 3k which means it's divisible by 3 and thus the original statement is false, the left side isn't $(2^{2n}-1)$

I'm just confused on where I'm going wrong with this proof? I'm like 80% positive that the left side in the n-1 function has to match the original left side equation, but I can't figure out a way of manipulating the equation for that to be true (with my current work as shown above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *very nearly* done.  You know that $4^{n-1} -1 = 3k$ for some $k$, which means $4^n-4 = 12k$, which means $4^n - 1 = 12k+3 = 3(4k+1)$.  So $3$ does divide $4^n-1$ after all, which is a contradiction since $n$ was assumed to be counterexample.  As a consequence, the set of counterexamples is empty.

Comment: I'm confused about how you got  $4^n-1 = 12k+3 = 3(4k+1)?$

Comment: Add $3$ to both sides of $4^n-4 = 12k$, then factor out $3$.